# Crop a video in Python, centered on a 16x9 video, cropped to 9x16, moviepy?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, crop, moviepy

I want to crop a video that is 16x9 resolution to 9x16. This can be done by cropping a centered 607px wide rectangle on the 16x9 video. Can this be done? EDIT: I do not care to stay within moviepy. I want to use something with speed. Currently, writing a 5 min video file with moviepy is taking 10+ minutes.

[image: cropping video from 16x9 to 9x16]

```py
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
import moviepy.editor as mpy

origVideo = 'video.mp4'
video = mpy.VideoFileClip(origVideo)

#Crop 'video' here and output 'cropped-video.mp4'

video.write_videofile('video-cropped.mp4')
```

Currently only getting a black screen with no audio. The video won't play, but it has a time code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @СергейКох I just added some additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moviepy.video.fx.all.crop`. Documentation are [here](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.crop.html). For example,

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy
from moviepy.video.fx.all import crop

clip = mpy.VideoFileClip("path/to/video.mp4")
(w, h) = clip.size

crop_width = h * 9/16
# x1,y1 is the top left corner, and x2, y2 is the lower right corner of the cropped area.

x1, x2 = (w - crop_width)//2, (w+crop_width)//2
y1, y2 = 0, h
cropped_clip = crop(clip, x1=x1, y1=y1, x2=x2, y2=y2)
# or you can specify center point and cropped width/height
# cropped_clip = crop(clip, width=crop_width, height=h, x_center=w/2, y_center=h/2)
cropped_clip.write_videofile('path/to/cropped/video.mp4')
```

The code is not tested. If there is any further question, please let me know.

Comment: I will test this as soon as I can. Currently having issues with write_videofile. It is exporting a black video with no sound, only a timecode.

Comment: This worked! I also found the github repository that does exactly what I am wanting, and it is very similar. Thank you very much! I used this line and it worked great. (w, h) = clip.size
cropped_clip = crop(clip, width=656, height=5000, x_center=w/2, y_center=h/2)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip,concatenate_videoclips
import moviepy.editor as mpy
from moviepy.video.fx.all import crop

# path of the video file to be cropped
path = '/home/lenovo/Videos/Youtube/ToCrop/'

# path of the video file to be saved after cropping
output_video = '/home/lenovo/Videos/Youtube/sample/'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    clip = mpy.VideoFileClip(path+filename)
    (w, h) = clip.size
    cropped_clip = crop(clip, width=600, height=5000, x_center=w/2, y_center=h/2)
    cropped_clip.write_videofile(output_video+filename)
```

Source: https://github.com/JerlinJR/Crop-a-Video/blob/main/crop.py

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74586467/4) to the question [Crop a video in Python, centered on a 16x9 video, cropped to 9x16, moviepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586467/crop-a-video-in-python-centered-on-a-16x9-video-cropped-to-9x16-moviepy) by the OP [Levfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20610256/levfo) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>